# RSpec: Bogus SQL Error?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a Photo model with the following method to search for associated tags by name:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings 
  ...

  def self.tagged_with( string )
    array = string.split(',').map{ |s| s.lstrip }
    joins(:tags).where('tags.name' => array ).group(:id)
  end

  ...
end
```

If I use this in the console it yields exactly what I would expect:

```
Photo.tagged_with('foo, bar, baz')
# Returns unique photos with tags named foo, bar, or baz
```

However, I tried to build this using a test in RSpec, and the test fails. Here's my test:

```
describe "tags" do
  it "should return a list of photos matching a string of tags" do
    t1 = Tag.create(:name=>'test')
    t2 = Tag.create(:name=>'bar')
    t1.photos << Photo.find(1,2,3)
    t2.photos << Photo.find(3,4)
    t1.save
    t2.save

    Photo.tagged_with('test').should have(3).photos
    Photo.tagged_with('bar').should have(2).photos
    Photo.tagged_with('test, bar').should have(4).photos
  end
end
```

This test fails with the following error:

```
  1) Photo tags should return a list of photos matching a string of tags
     Failure/Error: Photo.tagged_with('test').should have(3).photos
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, id AS id FROM "photos" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "photos"."id" = "taggings"."photo_id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "tags"."name" IN ('test') GROUP BY id
     # ./spec/models/photo_spec.rb:84:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So, the code works but the test fails. What am I doing wrong in my test?

Comment: Now as a matter of etiquette, I've got two of the same correct answer that both say the same amount of time ago... who was first?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/dealing-with-duplicate-answers

I think the consensus is "It doesn't really matter since 15 rep is not going to make or break anybody's day", but technically if you mouse hover over 'answered x mins ago' you get an actual timestamp in a tooltip, so you can tell whose was first.  Looks like I beat Mike by about 4 seconds. :)

Comment: Under the assumption both of them provided the same answer, and provided the issue as long with the solution at the same time... flip a coin :P

Comment: Ok, well, thank you both for your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it's complaining because you're grouping by id and both the photos and taggings tables have ids (The database doesn't know if you mean photos.id or taggings.id, hence the 'ambiguous' error).  Try changing `.group(:id)` to `.group('photos.id')` in your tagged_with method.

Comment: Ah, that did it. Brett, I owe you a beer or something, you've taught me a lot today.

Comment: @Andrew Haha, didn't even realize it was the same person asking until you mentioned it. No problem!

Answer (score 5):

To fix this error, be explicit on what you want to group by, so you would do:

```
joins(:tags).where('tags.name' => array ).group("photos.id")
```

Even if your code works now, with this query you really do want to be explicit. This is becuase all the tables that you are dealing with(taggings, and photos) both have an ID column.